# Count the number of rows of an aliased table

Tags: sql

```
select count (*) from
(select a.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0,a.STATUS as moov_profile_status,b.SUB_PLAN_ID,b.PLAN_ID,c.STATUS,c.NAME
from VMS_MOOV_PROFILE_T a, 
VMS_SUB_PLAN_NO_REGEN_T b,
VMS_VOUCHER_CONF_T c,    
where b.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0 = a.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0 
and c.VOUCHER_ID = (select f.VOUCHER_ID from VMS_PLAN_VOUCHER_T f where f.PLAN_ID = b.PLAN_ID));
```

This returns an error. How can I count the number of rows?

Comment: Provide an alias for the derived table `FROM (SELECT ...) x`

Comment: **What error?** What RDBMS are you using? I've guessed what your question is, but as you finished most words half-way through rather than attempting to write the entire word I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: P.S. you have an incorrect comma after `VMS_VOUCHER_CONF_T c,  `, which is probably the problem.

Comment: Post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

SELECT count (*)
FROM   (SELECT a.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0,
               a.STATUS AS moov_profile_status,
               b.SUB_PLAN_ID,
               b.PLAN_ID,
               c.STATUS,
               c.NAME
        FROM   VMS_MOOV_PROFILE_T a,
               VMS_SUB_PLAN_NO_REGEN_T b,
               VMS_VOUCHER_CONF_T c
        WHERE  b.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0 = a.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0
               AND c.VOUCHER_ID = (SELECT f.VOUCHER_ID
                                   FROM   VMS_PLAN_VOUCHER_T f
                                   WHERE  f.PLAN_ID = b.PLAN_ID)) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are:

1. You forgot to tell us what the error message is you got.
2. You forgot to tell us what dbms you are using.
3. There is a comma to many (after table alias c).
4. Depending on the dbms you may need also a name for the derived table (i.e. add some dummy name after the closing parenthesis).

The corrected query is:

```
select count (*) from
(
  select a.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0,a.STATUS as moov_profile_status,b.SUB_PLAN_ID,b.PLAN_ID,c.STATUS,c.NAME
  from VMS_MOOV_PROFILE_T a, 
  VMS_SUB_PLAN_NO_REGEN_T b,
  VMS_VOUCHER_CONF_T c
  where b.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0 = a.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0 
  and c.VOUCHER_ID = (select f.VOUCHER_ID from VMS_PLAN_VOUCHER_T f where f.PLAN_ID = b.PLAN_ID)
) dummy;
```

Moreover the way you join the tables (using a subquery on VMS_PLAN_VOUCHER_T) is a bit strange. And you shouldn't use the old comma-separated join syntax that was replaced in standard SQL more then twenty years ago. Plus: You don't need a derived table here anyway.

Here is your query simplified:

```
select count (*)
from VMS_MOOV_PROFILE_T a 
join VMS_SUB_PLAN_NO_REGEN_T b on b.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0 = a.ACCOUNT_POID_ID0 
join VMS_PLAN_VOUCHER_T f on f.PLAN_ID = b.PLAN_ID
join VMS_VOUCHER_CONF_T c on c.VOUCHER_ID = f.VOUCHER_ID;
```